# how to get specific column in Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, repository

I can GET below data by `findAll()` from db

```
[
   { id : 1,
     name : "John",
     age : "23",
     sex : "male"
   },
   { id : 2
...

]
```

And what I want to do is getting specific data from db like below.

```
[ 
   { id : 1,
     name : "John"
   },
   { id : : 1, 
     name : "Peter"
   }
...
]
```

so I tried like this.

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PersonDAO extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {

    @Query(value ="select p.id , p.name from person p", nativeQuery = true)
    Collection<Object> getPersonIdAndName();
}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping ("/getPersonIdAndName")
    public Collection<Object> getPerson() {
        return personDAO.getPersonIdAndName();
    }
```

but the result was like this (by postman)

```
[
    [
        1,
        "John"
    ],
    [
        2,
        "Peter"
    ]
....
]
```

I want a type `key : value`, not just value, 
because I want to fetch this to React.js state. 
how can I fix?
I'd appreciate for your help

Comment: Please read the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: now I solved. I just change ```Collection<Object>``` to ```List<Map<String, Object>>``` thx for your comment

Comment: Maybe you would add the new code as the answer, because it may be helpful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Use a Projection. Create a new Interface

```java
public interface PersonProjection {

    Integer getId();

    String getName();

}
```

After that in you repository use the projection in the return type

```java
@Repository
public interface PersonDAO extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    Query("select p.id, p.name from Person as p")
    Collection<PersonProjection> getPersonIdAndName();
}
```

Alternately, if you want to @Override the findAll() method you can create a customized repository. Here there is a GitHub repo example https://github.com/federicogatti/Spring-Custom-Repository-Example